# Google.com always forward me to google.com.hk

Tags: domain-name-system, google, country

Any one could help me to figure out why Google.com always forward me to google.com.hk?

```
  $ dig google.com
  www.google.com.         509426  IN      CNAME   www.l.google.com.
  www.l.google.com.       100     IN      A       74.125.71.147
  www.l.google.com.       100     IN      A       74.125.71.99
  www.l.google.com.       100     IN      A       74.125.71.105
  www.l.google.com.       100     IN      A       74.125.71.106
  www.l.google.com.       100     IN      A       74.125.71.104
  www.l.google.com.       100     IN      A       74.125.71.103
```

and

```
  $ dig google.com.hk
  www.google.com.hk.      261572  IN      CNAME   www.google.com.
  www.google.com.         589217  IN      CNAME   www.l.google.com.
  www.l.google.com.       139     IN      A       74.125.235.17
  www.l.google.com.       139     IN      A       74.125.235.18
  www.l.google.com.       139     IN      A       74.125.235.19
  www.l.google.com.       139     IN      A       74.125.235.20
  www.l.google.com.       139     IN      A       74.125.235.16
```

How to make my network always goes to google.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please visit below link that will help you to resolve your issue.

http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the google redirection, just use http://www.google.com/ncr , it will direct you to the google.com website even if you're located in another country.